# Any alternate command of Kubectl describe pods <podname>

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I am new to Dev Ops. I am setting up a CD pipeline in the VSTS. I have used Deploy to Kubernetes task to deploy the application, which is working fine.

After Deploy to Kubernetes task, I have added one more Deploy to Kubernetes task and I want to execute below command

`kubectl describe pods <podname>`

Above command describe about the pod.

I can see there is no such command available in the Deploy to Kubernetes task (in VSTS pipeline) for describe.

Only available commands are `get, apply, set, exec, login, logout, create, delete, expose, run and top`.

By executing above commands, I want to make sure is each pods is running.

How can I execute the describe command in the VSTS CD pipeline?

Alternative option is, any other command, which will return same output as `describe pods <podname>` command.

Comment: which data do you need from kubectl describe?

Comment: `kubectl get po name` returns state, so it provides what you ask for

Comment: @Amityo: Mainly I need below state                                                                    Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True

Comment: @4c74356b41: command not working.

Comment: what do you mean not working? lol

Comment: I also think that kubectl get pod <pod-name> will get you what you need

Comment: To execute the above command (mentioned by @4c74356b41) I have to provide full pod name like                              
                        kubectl get po <PodNameWithGuid>   
                        As I don't know the GUID value, it's difficult to execute the above command.                
                        I am looking for a command, which will provide the output with service name only (means without GUID)                             
                        e.g. kubectl describe pods myServiceName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use labels to find the pod you are interested in:

```
$ kg po --show-labels
NAME                                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       LABELS
frontend-76dc7bfc6d-7zcb8            1/1       Running   0          9h        app=Frontend,branch=develop,pod-template-hash=76dc7bfc6d
identityserverapp-f9684fc77-z9wtb    1/1       Running   0          9h        app=IdentityServerApp,branch=develop,pod-template-hash=f9684fc77

$ kg po --selector=app=Frontend
NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
frontend-76dc7bfc6d-7zcb8   1/1       Running   0          9h
```

ps. `kg` = alias for `kubectl get`

Answer (score -1):

If for any reason you need to script it from python, this is how it could be done.... (here I'm using jupyter magic, but the final fuction will convert to `subprocess` so it can be pure python)

```
#find all pods containing foobar 
namepods_per_node = !kubectl get pod -o=custom-columns=NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName --all-namespaces
# print ('\n'.join(pods_per_node))
print (pods_per_node[0])
pods_per_node_filtered = [ln for ln in pods_per_node if ln.find('foobar')!=-1]
print ('\n'.join(pods_per_node_filtered))
```

result:

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                                   STATUS      NODE
datalabs       foobar-deployment-5dbf985bdb-mllwp         Running     xxxxxxx.online-server.cloud
misc           foobar-second-deployment-85c5bd757f-fpm9z  Running     xxxxxxx.online-server.cloud
```

Then use get to get the json formated details and arrange by pod name:

```
#full node state:
pod_descriptions_txt = !kubectl get pods -o json --all-namespaces
pod_descriptions = json.loads(''.join(pod_descriptions_txt))
pod_descriptions = pod_descriptions['items']
pod_descriptions_by_name = {pod_desc['metadata']['name']:pod_desc for pod_desc in pod_descriptions}
```

Then print nodes with mounted volumes:

```
for ln in pods_per_node_filtered:
    pod_namespace, pod_name, pod_status, pod_node = ln.split()
    print(pod_name)
    # no machine readable format:    
    #     pod_desc = !kubectl describe pods {pod_name} --namespace {pod_namespace}
    pod_desc = pod_descriptions_by_name[pod_name]
    pod_volumes = pod_desc['spec']['volumes']
    for volume in pod_volumes:
        if 'persistentVolumeClaim' in volume:
            print (f"[{volume['name']:>34}]---> persistant[{volume['persistentVolumeClaim']['claimName']}]")
            assert len(volume)==2
        elif 'configMap' in volume:
            assert len(volume)==2
            print (f"[{volume['name']:>34}]---> configMap: {volume['configMap']}")
        elif 'secret' in volume:
            assert len(volume)==2
            print (f"[{volume['name']:>34}]---> secret: {volume['secret']}")
        elif 'hostPath' in volume:
            assert len(volume)==2
            print (f"[{volume['name']:>34}]---> hostPath: {volume['hostPath']}")
        else:
            print()
            print()
            print(volume)
            raise Exception('Todo')
```

Results to:

```
foobar-deployment-5dbf985bdb-mllwp
[                           some-pv]---> persistant[foobar-claim]
[               default-token-xxxxx]---> secret: {'defaultMode': 420, 'secretName': 'default-token-xxxxx'}
foobar-second-deployment-85c5bd757f-fpm9z
[                      someother-pv]---> hostPath: {'path': '/nfs/someother-pv', 'type': 'Directory'}
[               default-token-xxxxx]---> secret: {'defaultMode': 420, 'secretName': 'default-token-xxxxx'}
```

Can be combined to a function, along with more info on the volumes:

```
import subprocess
import json

def execute_command(cmd):
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    if result.returncode != 0:
        print(f"Error executing command: {cmd}")
        print(result.stderr.decode())
        return []
    return result.stdout.decode().splitlines()
def describe_pods(filter_str='foobar'):
    cmd = "kubectl get pod -o=custom-columns=NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName --all-namespaces"
    pods_per_node = execute_command(cmd)
    
    print(pods_per_node[0])
    
    pods_per_node_filtered = [ln for ln in pods_per_node if filter_str in ln]

    pod_descriptions_txt = execute_command("kubectl get pods -o json --all-namespaces")
    pod_descriptions = json.loads(''.join(pod_descriptions_txt))
    pod_descriptions = pod_descriptions['items']

    pod_descriptions_by_name = {pod_desc['metadata']['name']:pod_desc for pod_desc in pod_descriptions}

    for ln in pods_per_node_filtered:
        pod_namespace, pod_name, pod_status, pod_node = ln.split()
        
        pod_node_ip_txt = execute_command(f"kubectl describe node {pod_node} | grep InternalIP")
        assert len(pod_node_ip_txt) == 1
        pod_node_ip = pod_node_ip_txt[0].split()[1]
        
        print(f"POD  [{pod_name:>45}] on node [{pod_node}]({pod_node_ip}), namespace {pod_namespace}")

        pod_desc = pod_descriptions_by_name[pod_name]
        pod_volumes = pod_desc['spec']['volumes']

        for volume in pod_volumes:
            if 'persistentVolumeClaim' in volume:
                claimName = volume['persistentVolumeClaim']['claimName']
                print(f"  -    [{volume['name']:>30}]---> persistant[{claimName}]")
                pvc = execute_command(f"kubectl get pvc {claimName} --namespace {pod_namespace}")
                print("        " + "\n        ".join(pvc))
                assert len(pvc) == 2
                pv = pvc[1].split()[2]
                pv_descr = execute_command(f"kubectl describe pv {pv}")
                print("        " + "\n        ".join(pv_descr))
                assert len(volume) == 2
            elif 'configMap' in volume:
                assert len(volume) == 2
                print(f"  -    [{volume['name']:>30}]---> configMap: {volume['configMap']}")
            elif 'secret' in volume:
                assert len(volume) == 2
                print(f"  -    [{volume['name']:>30}]---> secret: {volume['secret']}")
            elif 'hostPath' in volume:
                assert len(volume) == 2
                print(f"  -    [{volume['name']:>30}]---> hostPath: {volume['hostPath']}")
            else:
                print()
                print()
                print(volume)
                raise Exception('Todo')
        print('====================================================================================================')
        print()
```

(names of nodes etc. changed for privacy reasons)